# Mischung im Wenn-Satz aus Indikativ und Konjunktiv

Tags: grammar, usage, subjunctive

Aus dem [Video zum Darts-WM-Finale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIXv9aUA3Ks), Minute 0:20 anfangend:

> **Steht**'s hier 2:2 nach den Legs, **ginge** es in die Verlängerung. Mann braucht dann zwei Legs Vorsprung. Und das schaukelt sich solange hoch, bis es womöglich 5:5 steht. **Kommt** es zu diesem 5:5, **gäbe** es ein Entscheidungsleg.

Warum benutzt der Kommentator zwei Sätze, in denen im ersten Teil der Indikativ verwendet wird, im zweiten aber der Konjunktiv? Wenn die beiden Teile einen Indikativ oder einen Konjunktiv erhalten würden, könnte ich sie nachvollziehen. Aber wie lassen die Sätze des Kommentators grammatikalisch rechtfertigen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es geht, ist aber etwas schwierig zu erklären.

Ein Konditionalsatz im Indikativ trifft eine allgemeingültige Aussage (ich lasse das "hier" bewusst weg)

> Steht's 2:2 nach den Legs, geht es in die Verlängerung.

Das gilt so in jedem Dart-Spiel in dieser Situation. Der Sprecher betont die Allgemeingültigkeit.

> Stünde es 2:2 nach den Legs, ginge es in die Verlängerung.

Der Sprecher betont die Spekulation über die weitere Entwicklung dieses Spiels, er stellt einen konkreten Bezug her.

> Steht's hier 2:2 nach den Legs, ginge es in die Verlängerung

Er mischt Allgemeingültigkeit und Bezug zum konkreten Spiel.

Der Nachteil eines reinen Konjunktivsatzes ist, dass er auch als pure hypothetische Annahme verstanden werden kann - so und so wäre es, es ist aber nicht so. Das Problem des reinen Indikativs ist, dass der Bezug zur aktuellen Situation nicht betont wird.

Insofern ist das eine sprachliche Feinheit.

Edith: Nach dem Grammatikduden (8. Auflage, 2009) wird unter § 752 erwähnt, dass man Indikativ und Konjunktiv im Konditionalsatz kombinieren, dann, wenn der Konjunktiv verwendet wird, um Potenzialität auszudrücken:

> Sollte sie aber schon zurück sein (potentiell zutreffend), so will ich mit ihr reden.

Es wird auf § 1775 verwiesen, da wird das Thema aber nicht mehr aufgegriffen.

Allerdings sollte nach der Logik die Verteilung genau anders rum sein. Denn der Stand ist die Möglichkeit, die Verlängerung wäre zwingende Folge.

Comment: +1 für die Rechtfertigung. Allerdings glaube ich, dass der Sprecher es einfach nur so dahingesagt hat.

Comment: Nun, er hat davor sicher nicht im Grammatikbuch nachgeschaut. Indikativ und Konjunktiv II sind aber zwei hochproduktive Paradigmata, die allgemein treffsicher verwendet werden. Wenn ein Mutterspracher dies verwendet, muss man davon ausgehen, dass er es richtig macht und mithin einen (unterbewussten) Grund dafür hat. Etwas anderes ist es, wenn jemand eine seltene Konstruktion falsch verwendet.

Comment: »Indikativ und Konjunktiv II sind aber zwei hochproduktive Paradigmata, die allgemein treffsicher verwendet werden.« – Das widerspricht ganz und gar meiner Erfahrung, inbesondere in der gesprochenen Sprache.

Comment: Muss es wirklich immer einen Grund geben? Dann wären also auch "Ich habe das gekauft gehabt" und das Berliner "Ick liebe dir" sinnvoll zu begründen.

Comment: Amüsanterweise wird Superplusquamperfekt vom Duden akzeptiert, weil es eine Belegstelle bei Goethe gibt. Das Superperfekt gilt hingegen als umgangssprachlich. Das verdeutlicht doch die ganze Willkür präskriptiver Grammatik. Ansonsten wären Beispiele für einen flächig falsch verwendeten Konjunktiv II/Indikativ mal interessant.

Comment: *Nach dem Grammatikduden (8. Auflage, 2009) wird unter § 752 erwähnt, dass man Indikativ und Konjunktiv im Konditionalsatz kombinieren, dann, wenn der Konjunktiv verwendet wird, um Potenzialität auszudrücken: »Sollte sie aber schon zurück sein (potentiell zutreffend), so will ich mit ihr reden.«* – Wer auch immer das geschrieben hat, hat leider übersehen, dass hier die Potentzialität hauptsächlich durch das Modalverb *sollen* ausgedrückt wird (das im Konjunktiv eine starke Bedeutungsänderung erfährt) und nicht durch den Konjunktiv.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Was aber auffallen sollte ist, dass der Konjunktiv II in Kombination mit Modalverben in einem völlig freistehenden Hauptsatz stehen kann. Damit bilden Konjunktiv II+Modalverb eine Einheit, die man meiner Ansicht nicht ohne weiteres getrennt betrachten kann.

Answer (score 1):

Kurzum: Nicht wirklich.

Ohne das Video jetzt gesehen zu haben, würde ich vermuten, dass der Kommentator wie die meisten Deutschen, die den Konjunktiv außerhalb von Höflichkeitsfloskeln überhaupt benutzen, diesen insbesondere in der gesprochenen Sprache mehr oder weniger willkürlich benutzt.

Insbesondere bei indirekter Rede und dem Irrealis, also den Hauptanwendungsfällen des Konjunktivs I bzw. II sowie im Potentialis (wie in Deinem Beispiel) beobachte ich es häufig, dass solche Sprecher ohne erkennbares Schema unabhängig vom grammatikalisch »richtigen« Modus zum Indikativ, Konjunktiv I, Konjunktiv II oder zur würde-Form greifen.

Nun kann man natürlich argumentieren, dass letzten Endes die Nutzer einer Sprache ihre Grammatik bestimmen, aber dies ist zum einen ein langwieriger Prozess, der sich (meines Wissens) noch nicht in Grammatikbüchern niedergeschlagen hat. Zum anderen tendieren Sprachen nicht dazu, eine derart großflächige Willkür lange zu dulden (es stürbe also der Konjunktiv in diesen Fällen aus).

Comment: Vielleicht wird es Zeit, unsere Grammatikbücher umzuschreiben ;)

Comment: Tja, nur was willst Du da schreiben? »In Konditionalsätzen ist die Wahl des Modus komplett frei und bedeutungslos«? (Siehe auch meine Änderung.)